# Viewing design II individual selection ratios

Tags: selection, adehabitathr

I've been using the R package adehabitat to calculate selection ratios for a project I'm working on involving preferences in animal foraging habitat.

When using the function `widesII` I can see the global (averaged) selection ratios for every animal I have put into the function, but not the selection ratios for each individual. However, if I plot selection ratio function, it will show me a line graph of these individual selection ratios.

How can I view a table of these individual selection ratios? I know they're there (since they are being graphed), but I don't know how to view them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation of adehabitatHS. In the following code selection ratios are estimted (Type II design)

```
library(adehabitatHS)
data(bighorn)

(wi <- widesII(bighorn$used, bighorn$availT, alpha = 0.1))
opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wi)
```

And confidence intervals (upper and lower) can be obtained consulting the list object. In this case upper CI `wi$ICwiupper` and lower `wi$ICwilower`.

All the best,